# postman doesn't send back data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

```
var express=require('express');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var {app1}=require('./todos2');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp');
**strong text**
var app=express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.post('todos2',(req,res)=>
{
    var todo=new app1({
        text:req.body.text
    });
    todo.save().then((docs)=>
    {
        res.send(docs);
    },(err)=>
    {
        res.status(404).send(err);
    });
});

app.listen(3000,()=>
{
    console.log('Starting port 3000');
});
```

*
        it's showing that CANNOT POST/todos2
        postman is not working can anyone explain why the request is not coming 
        back?????

Comment: have you ensured that you're requiring your `./todos2` properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are missing forward_slash in the routing, use this:

```
app.post('/todos2',(req,res)=>
{
    var todo=new app1({
        text:req.body.text
    });
    todo.save().then((docs)=>
    {
        res.send(docs);
    },(err)=>
    {
        res.status(404).send(err);
    });
});
```